# How do I use html inside a html helper-generated form (using razor syntax)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-to-vb.net

I am an ASP.NET MVC 3 noob learning by working my way thru the [wrox book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-1118076583.html)--but translating the code to VB because I work in a VB shop.

I am trying to translate this C# code into VB to generate a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(“Search”, “Home”, FormMethod.Get)) {
    <input type=”text” name=”q” />
    <input type=”submit” value=”Search” />
}
```

It seems like a fairly simple case of just replacing the braces, but I get the following errors from the compiler and can't figure out why.

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
      <input type="text" name="q" />            //   '>' expected.  
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>     //   '>' expected.  
End Using
```

I'm sure this is a simple sytnax issue, but I don't know the syntax yet. I'm also trying to understand HTML helpers and razor, so there is a lot of new stuff. Can someone explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the beginning of the html markup inside code blocks like inside `Using` with `@` or with `<text>`.

`@` is for single line:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
      @<input type="text" name="q" /> 
      @<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
End Using
```

`<text>` is for multi line:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
      @<text>
          <input type="text" name="q" />           
          <input type="submit" value="Search"/>    
      </text>
End Using
```

For more info see: [Combining text, markup, and code in code blocks](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode)

Comment: maybe you should add a different more descriptive title to your question: like how to use html inside Html.BeginForm in vb.net razor view or something like that

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
@Code 


End Code
```

Also see this at the end you have an example for combination
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic